# what we will call the variable var variableName='{}'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following syntax I do not  know what is a. Is it a string ??
    var a = '{}';
But I do know 
    var a = {}; 
Here 'a' in an object.

Comment: It's a string, possibly comprising a JSON encoded empty object.

Comment: Or, you know, just a string.

Comment: Also a string comprising of an empty Perl hash reference literal. There are lots of meaning that `{}` has, but without context there isn't much use in speculating on what this one is.

Comment: `stringify` version of `JSON` data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is a string. Anything you write in `''` will be treated as  a string

Here

```
 var a = '{}';
```

`a` will be a string whose value is `{}`. If you wanna check just write:

```
 alert(typeof a) //Output will be string
```

And yes you are write when you write

```
var a = {};
```

then `a` is your object

Answer (score 2):

```
[ quentin ][ quentin@raston ] %  node
> var a = '{}';
undefined
> typeof a
'string'
>
```

Yes, it is a string.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a string because you have it in `''`.